# Black screen instead of login screen. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 alongside with Windows 10. The problem is that after I choose Ubuntu in GRUB such a sequence follows:

Purple screen
Screen shut down
Black screen, but turned on

I can't see the login screen but I can hear a specific login sound. 
Such a situation happens in around 70%. Sometimes Ubuntu boots normally to login screen. What is more, after I switch Ubuntu into "stand-by" mode, when I try to mąkę it work again, similar things happen, the screen is completelly black, but on.
How can I solve this problem? 
My graphic card is Intel.

Comment: Have you tried backing up your data and re-installing Ubuntu? It isn't as hard as it sounds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I recommend to do the following.

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Enter the following above the line **exit 0**

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
```

Now edit the file /etc/default/grub and the change the following accordingly.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save and close file.Now run following command in Terminal to update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now restart PC.